# Facebook cdn Profile Picture Url Forbidden 403

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, facebook, sdk

I have been using the FB Javascript SDK for Oauth login in one of my angular apps. The GET request for the pictures url saved in my database throws a forbidden error after some time. and the image isn't loaded.The error is as follows

> GET
>   https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/…/v/t1.0-1/1932315_6892…d2094a24ec&oe=55BA91D0&**gda**=1433406112_11fe1a1d8f978807d686d002222c7e0b
>   403 (Forbidden)

Don't know why is this happening. Can Anyone please help ?

Comment: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/403error.htm

Comment: Don’t save Facebook CDN URLs in your database – they can change at any point.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the two underscore to both sides of the **gda** parameter

> https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/…/v/t1.0-1/1932315_6892…d2094a24ec&oe=55BA91D0&__gda__=1433406112_11fe1a1d8f978807d686d002222c7e0b

or maybe you have not permission to access that profile picture